# Getting duration between "Today" and "12 months before"

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code I want to upgrade it to get a duration between "Today" and "12 months before"

```
Dim today As String
    today = Date
    
 If IsDate(today) Then
        
        LastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)  
        FirstDay = LastDay - Day(LastDay) + 1
        
        myyear = Year(FirstDay)                            
        mymonth = Month(FirstDay)
        myfday = Day(FirstDay)
        mylday = Day(LastDay)
        
        Dim firstdate As String
        Dim lastdate As String
        
        firstdate = myyear & Chr(47) & mymonth & Chr(47) & myfday       
        lastdate = myyear & Chr(47) & mymonth & Chr(47) & mylday
        
    End If
```

can someone help how to upgrade this code ??

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.EOMonth`. `Dim Today As Date`... don't use a `String`. `Format$` will probably also be useful. Also, if you use a `Date`, then checking `IsDate` is superfluous.

Comment: Also use [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) to get a date which is say 12 months before today's date. For example `DateAdd("m",-12,date)`. The `minus` is for previous dates.

Comment: Or `WorksheetFunction.EDate` (that's what I meant in my original comment, instead of  `EOMonth`).

Answer (score 0):

The duration may vary depending on Leap Year occurrences:

```
Option Explicit

Sub duration()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, durasion As Long
    
    d1 = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))
    d2 = DateSerial(Year(d1) - 1, Month(d1), Day(d1))
    durasion = d1 - d2
    
    MsgBox d1 & vbCrLf & d2 & vbCrLf & durasion
    
End Sub
```

[image]

I am assuming that *"twelve months before"* means one year before, same month as before, same day as before.

Comment: Excel takes care of leap years. 2020 was a leap year, hence 366 days

Comment: Or simply `Debug.Print DateAdd("yyyy",-1,DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

> duration between "Today" and "12 months before"

That will be:

```
Duration = DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date), Date)
```